Query, giving back string, even if SELECT statement is empty, is faulty
simple question, but no idea, how to fix it.
Following Query should give back "No values", if SELECT Part will return nothing. I will get error message:
[21000][1241] (conn=80188403) Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What's wrong with this query?
SET @produktNummer = 01000051311;
SET @languageID = '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b';
SELECT IFNULL(
      (SELECT product.id, product_number, property_group_translation.name AS AttributBez
       FROM product
       LEFT JOIN product_property 
         ON product.id = product_property.product_id
       LEFT JOIN property_group_option 
         ON product_property.property_group_option_id = property_group_option.id
       LEFT JOIN property_group_translation 
         ON property_group_option.property_group_id = property_group_translation.property_group_id
       WHERE product_number = @produktNummer
          AND property_group_translation.language_id = UNHEX(@languageID)
          AND (
              property_group_translation.name = '' OR
              property_group_translation.name IS NULL
              )
       )
  ,'No values');

If I try without ISNULL(), I won't get any results. If I change Query like this, I will get multiple records back


SET @produktNummer = 01000051311;
SET @languageID = '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b';
SELECT product.id, product_number, property_group_translation.name AS AttributBez
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_property
ON product.id = product_property.product_id
LEFT JOIN property_group_option
ON product_property.property_group_option_id = property_group_option.id
LEFT JOIN property_group_translation
ON property_group_option.property_group_id = property_group_translation.property_group_id
WHERE product_number = @produktNummer
AND property_group_translation.language_id = UNHEX(@languageID)




The expected output is in the SELECT part. If there is no value, it should give back "No values" as a string. No idea, what u mean with ur comment

You can't do that. SQL is both statically and strongly typed. One consequence is that a single query must always return the same columns with the same names and the same datatypes - a query can't sometimes return fewer columns. What you'd need is code something like store query results in temp table, check number of rows, if 0 select string ELSE select from temp table But that's a bad idea (anti-pattern / code smell) as the signature of your code's return data would change. So, this becomes an xyproblem - Why do you want to do this? What do you think it achieves?

Well, result of this Query will be present in CSV file to another person, who doesn't understand SQL at all. It's easier for this person getting String "No values available" as to get empty response

That's a mistake. They should write code to handle a csv file with a header and no rows.  That's not a SQL issue, it's a data and software engineering issue.

So, it's not possible, what i want?

I already gave the pseudo code on how to do the wrong thing.

Your pseudo code is much to extensive. Don't want to be forced operating with views or temporary tables!

Don't do the wrong thing then.  SQL queries can't do the wrong thing without jumping through hoops. Because it's the wrong thing to do.

I won't comment anything any more. That's what I "don't do"

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can get at least 1 row with data or 'NoValue'.
Include other side parameters as subquery and join other data to them.
(
  select @produktNummer as produktNummer, UNHEX(@languageID) as languageID
  ) request

See example
SET @produktNummer = 01000051311;
SET @languageID = '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b';

SELECT produktNummer,languageID
  ,coalesce(product.id,'NoValue') id
  ,coalesce(product_number,'NoValue')product_number
  ,coalesce(property_group_translation.name,'NoValue') AS AttributBez
FROM (
  select @produktNummer as produktNummer, UNHEX(@languageID) as languageID
  ) request
left join product p on p.product_number = request.produktNummer 
LEFT JOIN product_property
   ON product.id = product_property.product_id
LEFT JOIN property_group_option
   ON product_property.property_group_option_id = property_group_option.id
LEFT JOIN property_group_translation
   ON property_group_option.property_group_id = property_group_translation.property_group_id
WHERE property_group_translation.language_id = request.languageID

If no data found, output is



produktNummer
languageID
id
product_number
AttributBez




01000051311
2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b
NoValue
NoValue
NoValue



Or



id
product_number
AttributBez




NoValue
NoValue
NoValue



If you want only check, whether is data present
SET @produktNummer = 01000051311;
SET @languageID = '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b';
SELECT 
   case when 
      (SELECT count(*)
       FROM product
       LEFT JOIN product_property 
         ON product.id = product_property.product_id
       LEFT JOIN property_group_option 
         ON product_property.property_group_option_id = property_group_option.id
       LEFT JOIN property_group_translation 
         ON property_group_option.property_group_id = property_group_translation.property_group_id
       WHERE product_number = @produktNummer
          AND property_group_translation.language_id = UNHEX(@languageID)
          AND (
              property_group_translation.name = '' OR
              property_group_translation.name IS NULL
              )
       )>0 then  'Values available'
    else 'No values'
    end result ;

Upd1.
If query result is dumped to csv-format file, all columns will be converted to strings.
SELECT ...
INTO OUTFILE '/out-files/products.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


This should contain a waning that it will implicitly coerce all numeric values to strings, even when they're not 'NoValue', which again is a code-smell / anti-pattern.

Yes. I implicitly assumed that the OP knows in what format the data is used next. If there is output in CSV, then conversion to a string is inevitable.

The problem may be that the OP does not rate highly the party receiving the data from him. However, it is always possible to negotiate)

No, a csv with 1,1,'x' is very different to a csv with '1','1','x'

Hats off and respect, Mr. ValNik. Ur solution characterized by a high level of expertise works perfect!
